# Is there an analytic way to tell if a system of ordinary differential equations is conservative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, jacobian

I don’t know the exact definition of *conservative,* but we can assume that *conservative* means the sum of Lyapunov exponents is zero. Is there an analytic method to show that a given system is conservative?
I came to this question by reading Sprott’s *Elegant Chaos.* A system of interest could be e.g.:

$$U''' + U' + \frac{1}{3}U^3 - Uc=0$$

where $c$ is constant, $U(t)$ is a function of time. It can be described as system of three equations:

$$\begin{align}
U' &= X \\
X' &= Y  \\
Y' &= -X - \frac{1}{3} U^3 +Uc
\end{align}$$

Then I think (but cannot prove it) that the trace of the Jacobian $\operatorname{Tr}(J)$ shows the conservativeness.

$$\operatorname{Tr}(J) = \frac{\partial U'}{\partial U} + \frac{\partial X'}{\partial X} + \frac{\partial Y'}{\partial Y} = 0 + 0 + 0 = 0$$

It also means that if $\operatorname{Tr}(J) < 0$, the system is dissipative, and if $\operatorname{Tr}(J) > 0$, the system diverges, i.e., it is not bounded. Can you say if I am right or wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hunches are absolutely right. In dynamical-systems theory, systems are often classified via their [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) (i.e., the trace of the Jacobian). In this context, if your dynamics is $\dot{x} = f(x)$, then $\operatorname{div} f = 0$ **defines** a conservative system; and $\operatorname{div} f < 0$ defines a dissipative one.

The only difficulty is that divergence may be inhomogeneous and thus you have to look at the average over a trajectory, which brings us to the sum of Lyapunov exponents.
However, *conservative* usually implies $\operatorname{div} f = 0$ everywhere.
A system with $\operatorname{div} f = 0$ on average would have to be carefully constructed.

This is linked with conservativity in the sense of energy conservation via [one of Liouville’s Theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)#Liouville_equations) and [Noether’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem): $\operatorname{div} f = 0$ implies a conserved phase-space volume, which imples symmetry with respect to the direction of time, which in turn implies conservation of energy (or a similar quantity). On the other hand, for Hamiltonian systems (which are energy-conserving), you have $\operatorname{div} f = 0$.

> if $\operatorname{Tr}(J) > 0$, the system diverges, i.e., it is not bounded.

Exactly. Your phase-space volume of an arbitrary set of initial conditions would always expand and thus you would the dynamics would have to be unbounded.